# Declaring multiple variables in one line, what is the order of their creation?

Tags: c++, variable-declaration

If I declare three variables in one line as below

```
ClassA a,b,c;
```

What is the order of their creation? 
Is the order defined by C++ standard or it depends on compiler?

Comment: In short the answer is "It is not defined by standard and depends on compiler"?